# Searching delay Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, search

**Searching Delay** 
Hi, i scrapping real time data and passing that data to Elastic search to index it. after indexing i am searching the result, time interval between indexing and searching is less then one second.so, i am get response of zero result found every time but when i check it through postman i get data.

```
 .then(record => {
       listofmovies = duplicate.removeDuplicate(record);
       results = listofmovies.concat(youtubemovies);
       console.log("results :" + results.length);
       return es.create(results);

    })
    .then(result=>{ 
      console.log("searching");
      return es.search(req.body.q);
    })
```

In the code es.create create the index and it return promise when this is complete i search the index which also return the promise.so how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch is called near-real time because there is a small lag between indexing a document and that document appearing in search.

You need to refresh the index so the documents appear in search, by default the refresh is done every 1 second, that's why the documents appear after 1 second when you use Postman.

In the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) you have some solutions, which involves setting the `refresh` parameter in your index request:

- Set refresh to `true`: Refresh after each index operation, the document will appear immediately.
- Set refresh to `wait_for`: With this your index request is going to wait until there is a refresh, so you will be able to check the document you just indexed in your search request in the Promise chain.

It depends on your use case, but you should be careful with making a lot of index operations with `refresh: true`, since it can bring the server to its knees.